# How do I use span tag in Slim?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

All I am trying to do is convert this line to Slim:

`<span id="slider-value"></span>`

but everything I have tried from the documentation prints out exactly what I typed and not the value of "slider-value"

Comment: `span id="slider-value"`

Comment: Then literally `span id="slider-value"` shows up in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have you file ending with the `.slim` extension (`your_file.html.slim`).

Then you will be able to write your `span` tag

```
span id="slider-value"
```

Answer (score 1):

So try this:

```
span#slider-value
```